# Is it reasonable to use resque(ruby) to manage external long-running commands (and log tasks)

Tags: ruby, linux, sinatra, resque

I have to run `bash heavy-job.sh <data-num>` (that takes 0.5~2 days) frequently on my  computer to process data located at ~/a/data/*num* . The script call a few sub-processes sequentially and write a log to ~/a/result/*num*.log . I have done this manually until now.

I wanted to visualize processed tasks and it's status(success or fail), etc as html table. I wrote simple sinatra app to render a table that shows

- the list of ~/a/data/*num* to be processed
- ~/a/result/*num*.log  exists or not (process not-launched/processing/done)
- it's status (the log file contains the word "error" or not)

I found that it would be convenient that if I could launch a `bash heavy-job.sh <data-num>` from the sinatra app, log the tasks (and info like time,date,etc..) and it's args (heavy-jobs takes some optional args ) and show them as html table. 
So I need something that manages jobs and logs to files (or db).
First I wrote a code like below for test (! for test, not integrated with my system yet !), but later I found [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) is what i wanted. I am a beginner and not sure if my decision is reasonable or not.

my questions are

- is it reasonable to use resque to manage external long-running commands (and log tasks)
- or should I use another tool (not necessarily ruby-tool).
- (extra;) the task-manager and the sinatra app should work separately (and communicate each other over REST or something) OR not ?

The jobs are not critical since I can retry tasks manually later if failed.
I am not good at English and my question may be misleading. I appreciate any help :) .

```ruby
class TaskSpawn

  def initialize()
    @pids = []
  end

  def spawn(command, options = {})
    #opt = {:pgroup => true}
    @pids << Kernel.spawn(command, options)
  end

  def pids()
    return @pids.clone
  end

  def waitany_nohang()
    delete_idx = nil
    ret = nil
    @pids.each_with_index do |p, idx|
      pid,status = Process.waitpid2(p, Process::WNOHANG)
      unless pid.nil?
        delete_idx = idx
        ret = [pid,status]
        break
      end
    end

    if delete_idx
      @pids.delete_at(delete_idx)
      return ret
    else
      # no task fininshed
      return nil
    end

  end 

  def waitall()
    ret = waitall
    raise "interal error" if ret.size != pids.size
    return ret
  end
end
```

Comment: I think if your own system is working, why not use it? It seems like a good use for Resque, but actually when I was considering this issue I decided to just roll my own implementation as well. See [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/122159/a-two-method-program-for-running-background-jobs) or [here](https://github.com/maxpleaner/tickers). But to reiterate, this is a good use for Resque.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking, you'll find a grammar-checker will help a lot. It'll help you avoid common errors such as not using proper capitalization and spelling. I'd recommend reading http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html also. You don't say what OS you're running on, but if it's *nix, look into using the standard cron capability and preprocess the information prior to needing it in Sinatra; That'll help your system feel more responsive.